# ImagePyramid tuning in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wms, geotiff-tiff, performance, image-pyramids

I am running several WMS layers from a *GeoServer* (2.2 RC3 at the moment of writing). All layers are *ImagePyramids* with sizes ranging from 100GB to 1TB in size.

I have read the [*GeoServer on Steroids*](http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/foss4g2011/gs_steroids_sgiannec_foss4g2011.pdf) several times and I'm probably missing half of it still. But there's a few things I'm wondering about.

My pyramids consists of 9-10 levels of GeoTIFF files, each level having 1/2 resolution of the previous. Each GeoTIFF has a file size with an average at around 8MB, a defined CRS and a size aspect ratio of 1:1.

1. Is my TIFF file size inefficient?
2. Will I get a performance boots by adding overview to my TIFF's?
3. Will *inner tiling* increase performance?
4. What could help me increase performance?
5. What have you guys learned from your experiments with ImagePyramids in GeoServer?

*1,3) In my view these two comes down to how a TIFF file is being handled in general and especially by GeoServer and I'm clueless here.*

*2) If I added overviews to my TIFF files my guess is that it corresponds to jump a level in the pyramid and thus I would only waste disk space?*

**Edit**: *Changed pyramid resolution from (the wrong) 1/4 to (the correct) 1/2. The pyramids are following the powers of 2 guidelines.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your tiff file is definitely inefficient, files around 1-2GB are normally better since GeoServer won't have to open as many files to generate the output.
Inner tiles help when you are zoomed in and need only to access a portion of the file.
Having a 4 times jump between levels will improve disk occupation, but will also slow down image serving and also quality of the output.

The rest I already wrote in the presentation ;-)

Comment: I guess you're saying, that its more efficient to use *inner tiling* and search for the required tiles *inside* a TIFF file than searching for the required tiles as *individual* TIFF files. I can follow that one.

But does it make sense to use *overviews* if I'm creating a pyramid? If I follow the first part of this comment, having more than one TIFF file, a pyramid is more efficient due to the number of TIFF files GeoServer needs to access?

Comment: The problem with the pyramid above is that it follows powers of 4 instead of 2, that's why I'm recommending adding overviews anyways (one level of overviews).

Comment: Ahh... I see what you mean, and I see my own mistake. The pyramids are actually following the powers of 2, but I have confused my self (and everybody else) by writing *resolution* as a description instead of *size*. I guess I was thinking in *sizes* while using the more precise term *resolution*. Never the less, I get your point now :)